# Jmeter:- How to increase and Decrease and then increase decrease TPS using jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, application-software-testing

I have 300 VUsers (Threads) and ramp up 600 seconds and total number of requests (http Request) 5 , Response time for each request is 2 seconds so total 10 sec will takes to complete one loop,

I was using 2.13 Jmeter Version but now moved to Jmeter 4.0 Version.

App Server : Linux

Jmeter Placed at Windows Server which highly configured and High Bandwidth and placed in USA.

Scenario like given Below.

```
Login Application 
Create Order 
Active Order 
Disconnect Order 
Cancel Order
```

I want to Achieve TPS like given below

```
1 TPS to 10 TPS for 60 Minutes 
2 TPS to 4 TPS for next 60 Minutes 
2 TPS to 8 TPS for next 60 Minutes  
... and so on
```

I have used "jp@gc - Throughput Shaping Timer" But unable to achieve expected TPS.

```
Start RPS    End RPS    Duration

 1           10         3600

 2           4          3600

 2           8          3600
```

- Total Number of Users- 300
- Ramp Up 600 Seconds
- Duration of Test 10800 Seconds
- Targeted TPS 1-10 TPS
- Achieved TPS 2 TPS

Please suggest what should I do to achieve such Fluctuated TPS

Please suggest the strategy need to follow.

Which Plug in I can use and how to calculate TPS in it.

Answer (score 1):

It might be the case your application simply cannot respond as fast as you're expecting it to do, i.e. if you're able to achieve only 2 TPS it means that application cannot process more than 20 requests per second.

So I would recommend looking on Linux host instead of trying to manipulate JMeter settings, the reasons could be in:

- your Linux server simply lacks resources (CPU, RAM, Network, etc.) so make sure to monitor the above metrics using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)
- your application infrastructure configuration isn't suitable for high loads, i.e. application server and/or database are running on developer default settings in terms of thread pools or allocated memory
- your application is using inefficient algorithms or operates large data objects, try re-running your load test and enable [profiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) tool telemetry to detect where your application is spending the most time, it could be caused i.e. by recursive long function call or slow DB query

Comment: Thank You So much for your valuable time,
I have tested this application and I was able to achieve   45 TPS Max.
I have performed many scenario where TPS was keep on Increasing but i am failed to achieve Fluctuated TPS as mentioned above scenarios

Comment: Can anyone please help me on this